Error re-compiling Ubuntu Jammy HWE kernel 6.8.0-45
I’m currently trying to compile a custom Ubuntu Jammy (22.04) HWE kernel, version 6.8.0-45, by following a procedure similar to the one mentioned here. I’m applying some patches to the iwlwifi driver.
Here’s my step-by-step process:

git clone git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/jammy && cd jammy
git checkout Ubuntu-hwe-6.8-6.8.0-45.45_22.04.1
git switch -c my_branch/6.8.0-45_iwl_patch
Apply my changes to drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwl-nvm-parse.c file
git add . && git commit -m "My commit message"
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
sed -i 's/CONFIG_LOCALVERSION=""/CONFIG_LOCALVERSION="-ricciolino"/g' .config
make oldconfig
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic

Everything works fine until step 10, where I encounter the following error during the build process:
(my_branch/6.8.0-45_iwl_patch)> fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic
Debug: /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/stamps/stamp-prepare-indep
dh_prep -i
[ -d /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/stamps/ ] || mkdir /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/stamps/; touch /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/stamps/stamp-prepare-indep
Debug: /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/stamps/stamp-install-headers
dh_testdir
install -d /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45/usr/src/linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45
find . -path './debian' -prune -o -path './debian.hwe-6.8' -prune \
  -o -path './include/*' -prune \
  -o -path './scripts/*' -prune -o -type f \
  \( -name 'Makefile*' -o -name 'Kconfig*' -o -name 'Kbuild*' -o \
     -name '*.sh' -o -name '*.pl' -o -name '*.lds' \) \
  -print | cpio -pd --preserve-modification-time /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45/usr/src/linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45
27658 blocks
cp -a scripts include /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45/usr/src/linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45
(find arch -name include -type d -print | \
        xargs -n1 -i: find : -type f) | \
        cpio -pd --preserve-modification-time /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45/usr/src/linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45
xargs: warning: options --max-args and --replace/-I/-i are mutually exclusive, ignoring previous --max-args value
cpio: /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45/usr/src/linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45/arch/powerpc/include/uapi/asm/Kbuild not created: newer or same age version exists
...
<more cpio lines>
...
cpio: /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45/usr/src/linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45/arch/x86/include/asm/Kbuild not created: newer or same age version exists
28358 blocks
# Do not ship .o and .cmd artifacts in headers
find /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45/usr/src/linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45 -name \*.o -or -name \*.cmd -exec rm -f {} \;
[ -d /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/stamps/ ] || mkdir /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/stamps/; touch /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/stamps/stamp-install-headers
Debug: binary-headers
dh_installchangelogs -plinux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45
dh_installdocs -plinux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45
dh_compress -plinux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45
dh_fixperms -plinux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45
dh_installdeb -plinux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45
flock -w 60 /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/.LOCK dh_gencontrol -plinux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45
dh_md5sums -plinux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45
dh_builddeb -plinux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45
dpkg-deb: building package 'linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45' in '../linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45_6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1_all.deb'.
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 debian/scripts/fix-filenames.c -o debian/scripts/fix-filenames
Debug: /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/stamps/stamp-prepare-tree-generic
install -d /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/build/build-generic
touch /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/build/build-generic/ubuntu-build
python3 debian/scripts/misc/annotations --export --arch amd64 --flavour generic > /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/build/build-generic/.config
sed -i 's/.*CONFIG_VERSION_SIGNATURE.*/CONFIG_VERSION_SIGNATURE="Ubuntu 6.8.0-45.45~22.04.1-generic 6.8.12"/' /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/build/build-generic/.config
find /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/build/build-generic -name "*.ko" | xargs rm -f
make ARCH=x86 CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-linux-gnu- HOSTCC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 CC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 BINDGEN=bindgen-0.65 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.0-45-generic CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y KBUILD_BUILD_VERSION="45~22.04.1" CFLAGS_MODULE="-DPKG_ABI=45" PYTHON=python3 O=/opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/build/build-generic -j24 rustavailable || true
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/my-kernel/jammy'
make[2]: Entering directory '/opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/build/build-generic'
***
*** Rust bindings generator 'bindgen-0.65' could not be found.
***
***
*** Please see Documentation/rust/quick-start.rst for details
*** on how to set up the Rust support.
***
make[3]: *** [/opt/my-kernel/jammy/Makefile:1718: rustavailable] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/opt/my-kernel/jammy/Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/build/build-generic'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/my-kernel/jammy'
make ARCH=x86 CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-linux-gnu- HOSTCC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 CC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 BINDGEN=bindgen-0.65 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.0-45-generic CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y KBUILD_BUILD_VERSION="45~22.04.1" CFLAGS_MODULE="-DPKG_ABI=45" PYTHON=python3 O=/opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/build/build-generic -j24 olddefconfig
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/my-kernel/jammy'
make[2]: Entering directory '/opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/build/build-generic'
***
*** The source tree is not clean, please run 'make ARCH=x86 mrproper'
*** in /opt/my-kernel/jammy
***
make[3]: *** [/opt/my-kernel/jammy/Makefile:646: outputmakefile] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/opt/my-kernel/jammy/Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/build/build-generic'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/my-kernel/jammy'
make: *** [debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:23: /opt/my-kernel/jammy/debian/stamps/stamp-prepare-tree-generic] Error 2

What is wrong ?
Thanks for suppoort

It says to run  please run make ARCH=x86 mrproper
*** in /opt/my-kernel/jammy. Did you try this?

Yes I tried but after the mrproper the config file I copied for applying my current kernel configuration gets deleted, and it's not want I want...

I think I understand what was wrong.
I just created a GitHub gist with all updated steps.
I report them here also:
# Clone Ubuntu stock Kernel repo
git clone git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/jammy
cd jammy
git checkout Ubuntu-hwe-6.8-6.8.0-45.45_22.04.1
# Build deps
sudo apt build-dep linux linux-image-unsigned-`uname -r`
sudo apt install build-essential libncurses-dev bison flex libssl-dev libelf-dev fakeroot libncurses-dev gawk flex bison openssl libssl-dev dkms libelf-dev libudev-dev libpci-dev libiberty-dev autoconf llvm dwarves
# Clean all
fakeroot debian/rules clean && make ARCH=x86 mrproper && git clean -fd && git restore . && git clean -fd && git restore .
# do custom changes
code debian.hwe-6.8/changelog # Append custom version
code include/linux/uts.h # Modify UTS_SYSNAME
# Update Debian configs
chmod a+x debian/rules && chmod a+x debian/scripts/* && chmod a+x debian/scripts/misc/*
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
# Start build
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic

Particularly important is the fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs step, before final fakeroot command for starting the build.

Please don't put SOLVED in the question title in this site. You can accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ☑️ next to your answer and turn it green ✅.

@user68186 I am going to click gray checkmark in 3 hours (AU does not let me click yet), thank you for your observation
